# Polkadot.js: How do I fetch all rewards paid to a specific nominator that resulted from a specific validator?

Tags: polkadot-js

I have tried using api/packages/api-derive/src/staking/erasRewards.ts, but I do not understand what titrates the number of eras being shown. Also, whose rewards am I looking at? All rewards in that given era?

Here's my code snippet:

```
const data = await api.derive.staking.erasRewards(); 
console.log(data.map(n => n['era'].toHuman() + ": " + n['eraReward'].toHuman()));
```

out:

```
[
  '727: 2,551,955,748,462,398',
  '728: 2,563,279,047,583,848',
  '729: 2,563,370,718,401,581',
  '730: 2,566,416,999,724,756',
  '731: 2,579,735,528,770,578',
  '732: 2,580,391,954,273,350',
  '733: 2,574,770,240,650,025',
  '734: 2,574,423,145,452,759',
  '735: 2,572,961,896,036,511',
  '736: 2,572,752,562,942,962',
  '737: 2,575,640,277,891,519',
  '738: 2,575,174,055,033,005',
  '739: 2,572,164,587,614,876',
  '740: 2,574,636,183,355,342',
  '741: 2,575,348,329,001,013',
  '742: 2,556,461,500,268,646',
  '743: 2,556,729,480,475,956',
  '744: 2,557,482,295,343,475',
  '745: 2,533,870,094,301,476',
  '746: 2,527,530,013,839,401',
  '747: 2,527,804,229,223,442',
  '748: 2,528,033,816,896,959',
  '749: 2,533,785,921,746,221',
  '750: 2,534,274,185,050,776',
  '751: 2,538,036,804,329,962',
  '752: 2,537,897,849,156,071',
  '753: 2,537,564,847,212,898',
  '754: 2,538,531,966,424,070',
  '755: 2,539,108,793,068,694',
  '756: 2,540,608,123,105,699',
  '757: 2,540,897,813,019,624',
  '758: 2,540,220,548,628,705',
  '759: 2,540,499,187,276,898',
  '760: 2,535,471,076,137,138',
  '761: 2,537,161,861,178,588',
  '762: 2,537,712,672,567,210',
  '763: 2,538,354,552,093,822',
  '764: 2,539,370,254,053,080',
  '765: 2,539,498,967,691,432',
  '766: 2,537,985,738,070,300',
  '767: 2,539,672,793,438,627',
  '768: 2,547,647,218,090,372',
  '769: 2,548,407,690,287,302',
  '770: 2,549,213,979,480,129',
  '771: 2,541,633,869,358,439',
  '772: 2,547,817,357,135,217',
  '773: 2,547,432,369,360,853',
  '774: 2,547,718,144,532,895',
  '775: 2,549,267,291,525,198',
  '776: 2,550,814,915,082,432',
  '777: 2,551,440,540,362,707',
  '778: 2,553,256,619,503,668',
  '779: 2,552,954,215,201,388',
  '780: 2,553,460,158,045,053',
  '781: 2,556,438,206,416,740',
  '782: 2,558,118,980,257,812',
  '783: 2,559,147,608,644,081',
  '784: 2,560,633,251,102,886',
  '785: 2,562,597,178,237,471',
  '786: 2,562,751,449,521,687',
  '787: 2,566,234,007,347,650',
  '788: 2,565,712,211,377,681',
  '789: 2,566,815,672,241,032',
  '790: 2,567,044,191,299,448',
  '791: 2,567,605,353,041,866',
  '792: 2,568,789,496,998,416',
  '793: 2,567,509,775,385,522',
  '794: 2,569,839,818,841,921',
  '795: 2,569,981,058,027,446',
  '796: 2,566,746,092,399,327',
  '797: 2,566,853,946,849,154',
  '798: 2,567,661,511,732,652',
  '799: 2,567,730,503,536,287',
  '800: 2,572,088,096,172,078',
  '801: 2,570,797,107,149,885',
  '802: 2,572,428,261,633,356',
  '803: 2,576,551,669,974,451',
  '804: 2,577,565,186,348,720',
  '805: 2,578,034,696,990,158',
  '806: 2,578,387,595,911,190',
  '807: 2,578,369,699,479,845',
  '808: 2,578,868,063,338,523',
  '809: 2,579,517,724,773,635',
  '810: 2,574,743,424,098,730'
]
```

I also tried using api/packages/api-derive/src/staking/stakerRewards.ts, but I kept getting an empty array output.

Code:

```
const data = await api.derive.staking.stakerRewards('11uMPbeaEDJhUxzU4ZfWW9VQEsryP9XqFcNRfPdYda6aFWJ');
console.log(data)
```

Out:

```
[]
```

How do I fetch all the rewards paid to a specific account?

Comment: This post may help: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4256/using-polkadot-js-api-how-can-we-list-the-members-of-a-kusama-nomination-pool

Comment: How to use the Staking::Rewarded and Staking::PayoutStarted? Can you give me a example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking at from your first query is the **total** payout of the whole era. It amounts to about 255k DOT.

The information of past payouts is stored in events. It is not held in storage permanently as that would only inflate the storage. This information is therefore not available in a standard Polkadot node.

You either need:

- An archive node, since that stores all past events.
- An indexing service that stores these events and makes them queryable for you.

In case you have that, the `Staking::Rewarded` event contains the receiver and the amount of each payout.
A `Staking::PayoutStarted` event before that indicates from which era and validator the rewards are.

Comment: Thank you! I was quite lost. Do you know of a list of archive nodes I can connect to?